# how to call phone when email come?

Tags: blackberry

I am getting the notification and my method is also called  public void messagesAdded .I also get the subject of mail .But I want to call a number whenever I got mail But my phone call function not work (not call the phone number) here is my code?

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.Invoke;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.PhoneArguments;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.FolderEvent;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.FolderListener;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.StoreEvent;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.StoreListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Folder;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.NoSuchServiceException;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Session;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Store;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen  implements FolderListener, StoreListener
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("MyTitle");
   // makeCall("9891234175");

        try {
             Store s = Session.waitForDefaultSession().getStore();
              Folder[] folders = s.list(Folder.INBOX);
              System.out.println(folders);

              Folder inbox = folders[0];
              System.out.println(inbox);
              inbox.addFolderListener(this);

        } catch (NoSuchServiceException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


    }

    public void makeCall(String data){
        String phoneNumber = data;
        if ( phoneNumber.length() == 0 ){
            System.out.println("Error,  not a phone number");
        }
        else {
            PhoneArguments call = new PhoneArguments (PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL,phoneNumber);
            Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, call);
        }   
}

    public void batchOperation(StoreEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------"+e.getSource());
        //makeCall("9891234175");
    }

    public void messagesAdded(FolderEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message orginalMessage = e.getMessage();

          if( e.getMessage().isInbound() == true )
          {
              String subject = orginalMessage.getSubject();
                 System.out.println("++++++++++++++++"+subject);
              //message is a new received message
              //perform some task here
              UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    PhoneArguments call = new PhoneArguments (PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL,"9891234175");
                    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, call);
                     //  makeCall("9891234175");

                }
            });
          }
    }

    public void messagesRemoved(FolderEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question along with a number of related issues, has actually been asked and answered on the BB forum here:

[email interaction question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-check-email-coming-from-some-subject/m-p/2797227#M225630)

In summary, the email listener code does not run on the same context as the application.  So (in common with most listener processing), the recommendation is to move the processing of the event into the application context using a Global Event. Documentation here:

[Global Events](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Global-Events-and-Global-Event-Listeners/ta-p/444814)